# Opera throws a Security error on nodeType in jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

Since updating jQuery to 1.9.1, Opera started to throw errors related to nodeType.

I have the code below:

```
$("p, td, div, span").children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType == 3)
    {
        ...
    }
});
```

And Opera throws

> Unhandled Error: Security error: attempted to read protected variable

Even if I remove that code block, Opera throws the same error, this time on a line in `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` itself:

```
return e.nodeType ? (this.context = this[0] = e, this.length = 1, this) : b.isFunction(e) ? r.ready(e) : (e.selector !== t && (this.selector = e.selector, this.context = e.context), b.makeArray(e, this))
```

If that changes anything, I'm loading jQuery from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

UPDATE:

That same code results in a similar error in Firefox:

```
Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'
```

Everything works as expected in Chrome.

Comment: What node is it? Some context please, otherwise we'll need to close as "*could not reproduce*" :-)

Comment: I've updated the snippet in the question.

Comment: [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) is deprecated since v1.8, but I don't think that's the reason. Could you show us the DOM on which those selectors are applied?

Comment: Changed to addBack, didn't help. Also, as mentioned above, I get the error even if I remove my code block entirely. It just throws the same error on another nodeType, inside jquery.

Comment: Yeah, I expected it to be an iframe issue. `$("p, td, div, span").children().andSelf()` does have an `<iframe>` selected, doesn't it? [`.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) tries to access it.

Comment: I've tried `$("p, td, div, span").not('iframe')` but that didn't solve anything.

Comment: Obviously `p, td, div, span` does not select iframes, but one of their `children()` might be

Comment: Also tried `if ($(this).not('iframe') && this.nodeType == 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$("p, td, div, span").children().addBack().not("iframe").contents()` for not applying [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) on iframes.

Btw, if you only want to get content nodes with `nodeType == 3`, you might rather just use `.children()`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. Wouldn't .children() also select other tags inside the p's, td's, etc.?

Comment: Yes, it does. And that seems to be your problem.